# Draw abline through points from a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a line through points on a plot. Each plot is a chromosome. The x-axis is the sampleID and the y-axis is the correlation between one sample and sample 17. All Im trying to do is draw a linear trend line between the points. However when I use abline as below I get the errorbelow and Im not sure how to correct it. I've moved the abline to the correct bit of the code but no resolution>

[image]

```
 #Get the data as display it
 df <- read.delim("~/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/blabla.txt", header=TRUE)
 df[,order(names(df))]
 ind = unique(as.character(df$chr))
 for(jj in ind){
  indic = which(df$chr == jj)
  plot(i, corrie, xlim=c(0,22), ylim=c(0.7,1), pch=19, type="s", xlab="sample", ylab="r",     main=jj)
  for(i in 3:16) {
corrie = (cor(df[,i][indic], df[,15][indic]))
points(i,corrie)
 }
abline(lm(corrie ~ i))
}


Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  'a' and 'b' must be finite
```

Example data:

```
 chr         column3     column4      column5  etc..
 chr9      14.44324324  11.66666667 14.13333333 
 chr9      22.93333333  7.20000000  9.13333333  
 chr9      15.60000000  5.86666667  5.73333333  
 chr10     3.06666667   8.46666667  1.80000000  
 chr12     10.333333        12.133333   7.000000    
 chr18    4.60000000    5.66666667  8.40000000  
 chr9      16.33333333  13.20000000 19.86666667 
 chr9      3.66666667   10.73333333 17.73333333 
 chr9      15.06666667  11.80000000 14.200000   
chr2      7.800000      10.933333   7.066667
```

Comment: it's better if you include the smallest possible reproducible example. I.e. fewest lines of code and we can copy and paste it and it will run. You might even find the problem yourself that way.

Comment: OK. Just run from ind = unique(as.character(df$chr))

Comment: Your code seems faulty to me. There is an object `i` that is used outside the loop in which it is used. Try moving the `plot` call into the for loop. Your problem with the `abline` call is that `corrie` and `i` are single values. This linear model is impossible to estimate and therefore `abline` complains.

Comment: Hi Simon G. There are two for loops here. SO I moved the plot call to within the for(i in 1 in 3:16) but i got the error:  Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : object 'corrie' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a blind attempt at solving your problem as you didn't give any example data. My recommendation would be that you format the data that you want to plot before your start plotting.

In your example you want to calculate the correlations using the for-loop over `i`. So you can just do this within this loop and save all the correlations in a data.frame. When you have gathered all the data that go into the plot, you can draw these by calling `plot` and `abline` on the new data.frame.

This you can repeat for all chromosomes (the loop over `jj`). You can add a line that saves the plot to separate in that loop.

```
for(jj in ind){
  indic <- which(df$chr == jj)

  plot.df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 3:16) {
    corrie <- (cor(df[,i][indic], df[,15][indic]))
    plot.df <- rbind(plot.df, c(i, corrie))
  }
  colnames(plot.df) <- c("sample", "cor")

  plot(cor ~ sample, data=plot.df, xlim=c(0,22), ylim=c(0.7,1), pch=19,
       type="p", xlab="sample", ylab="r", main=jj)
  abline(lm(cor ~ sample, data=plot.df))
}
```

Comment: OK Thanks Simon G. As I was putting in example data you have sorted it with the above. Cheers